# inline edit in react.js failed to open single item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on edit I expect only 1 row to be affected. However, all rows were affected, what have I done wrong?

```
..
renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
         <li key={i}> {this.state.isEdit ? this.renderEditForm() : item} {this.ItemCtrl(i)}</li>)
     )
   }
..
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkum8mep

Answer (score 0):

each row is listening to the same isEdit state, so when you change isEdit to true, then they will all update to editing since they all have that same property. if you want, you can have an object [{item: 1, editing: false}] for example and set the editing state for the specific index clicked.

Comment: hmm but says I have the items come from backend, I have to inject extra property isEdit equal to false during initialization? that's strange.

Comment: @Sandy You could also do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/v3hrLcsk/ where you set isEdit to the index of the item that's being edited

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update it. Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/v3hrLcsk/1/

Comment: great, just a very minimal change

Comment: one more problem, it's best to hide the control buttons : edit and delete when user is editing.

Comment: Then you only want to display this.ItemCtrl when this.state.isEdit != i like this http://jsfiddle.net/v3hrLcsk/2/